# How to iterate through an array containing objects - javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have an array containing objects that looks like this:

```
[{\"user\":\"mcnewsmcfc\",\"num\":11},{\"user\":\"ManCityFNH\",\"num\":7}];
```

I am then using:

```
var jsonu = JSON.parse(tweets.replace(/&#34;/g, '\"'));
```

to remove all the unwanted characters from the array. My question is then how to iterate through the array and (EDIT) use the values of "user" and "num" for each object in the table (EDIT).

This is what I initally have but this does not extract the correct values:

```
for (var u in jsonu) {
    var row = $('<row></row>');
    row.append('<th>' + jsonu[u][0] + '</th><td>' + jsonu[u][1] + '</td>');
    $('#userTable').append(row);
}
```

Comment: Do you have an array or a string version of an array? Show us complete code..

Comment: Why not try using `underscore.js`? They have some very powerful functions that could make this a breeze. (Work smart, not hard ;) )http://underscorejs.org/     Specifically to your question, they have a method that will return the array omitting specific keys that you :blacklist". The method is called `_.without([...], keys);`

Comment: [lodash](https://github.com/lodash/lodash) is better than underscore

Comment: @dato "Better" is relative and subjective :)

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan yes it is a string version of the array

Comment: Apologise it seems I have worded my question wrong, I don't want to remove them I want to return their values for each object to be put in a HTML table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var tweets = '[{\"user\":\"mcnewsmcfc\",\"num\":11},{\"user\":\"ManCityFNH\",\"num\":7}]';
var jsonu = JSON.parse(tweets.replace(/&#34;/g, '\"'));

for (var u in jsonu) {
    var row = $('<row></row>');
    row.append('<th>' + jsonu[u].user + '</th><td>' + jsonu[u].num + '</td>');
    $('#userTable').append(row);
}
```

since `jsonu` is an array, u is just the index in the array. `jsonu[u]` will return back the object at that index in the array, which is a javascript object.

So to access the user and num property, simply call `jsonu[u].user` and `jsonu[u].num`